# Encapsulation in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin

I started my studies in Kotlin and I'm trying to solve this problem:

First: Create a class to represent a person with the private attributes of name, year of birth and height.

Second: Create one public method for sets/gets and another one to print all the data from the person.

Third: Create a method to calculate the age.

When I turned private the attributes, I couldn't access them anymore. How can I use the getters and setters to access the attributes?

My code:

```
fun main() {
val dataJohn = Data()
dataJohn.name = "John"
dataJohn.height = 1.83
dataJohn.birth_year= 1948
println(dataJohn.birth_year)
println(dadosJoao.height)
println(dadosJoao.calculateAge())
}

class Data {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    var height = 0.0
    var birth_year = 0

fun calculateAge(age: Int)  {
    age = 2021 - birth_year
    return this.age
    }
}
```

Comment: "one public method for sets/gets" is odd. They want you to make a `getAndSet` method for each property? That is a very rare need in practice. And typically, Kotlin doesn't use getter and setter methods because properties are available.

Comment: Was the problem written to be done in Kotlin, or in Java?

Answer (score 0):

That’s because what is done in Java (I.e making variables final and exposing via getters and setters) is creating a property. This is done in Kotlin by just declaring your variable with val or var. When marking it as private though the property is only accessible within the class and its like making the getters and setters private in Java. You can therefore omit the private part.